# ReactJS SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs

I have this snippet of ReactJS Code that's worked until after I added a few more div elements at the top of the `render`. In there are 3 bootstrap radio buttons which I intended to link some initial values to initial values on the constructor so I can change them only from the constructor.

```
class Body extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = { 
           data : [],

           first_active: 'active',
           second_active: '',
           third_active: '',

           joke_id: 1,
           dadjoke_id: 1,
           tweet_id: 1,

           first_checked: 'checked',
           second_checked: '',
           third_checked: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
     this.postdata()
    }

    postdata(){
        ...
    }

    render(){
       return( 
            <div>
              <div id="side-nav">
                <div className="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                  <label className="btn btn-secondary {first_active}">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autoComplete="off" value="Joke" ref_id="{joke_id}" {first_checked} onChange={() => alert('click1')} /> Joke
                  </label>
                  <label className="btn btn-secondary {second_active}">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autoComplete="off" value="DadJokes" ref_id="{dadjoke_id}" {second_checked}  onChange={() => alert('click2')} /> DadJokes
                  </label>
                  <label className="btn btn-secondary {third_active}">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autoComplete="off" value="Tweet" ref_id="{tweet_id}" {third_checked} onChange={() => alert('click3')} /> Tweet
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
                <div className="col-md-7 top-padding" align="center">
                      <span className="oi oi-reload"></span>
                    </div>
                {this.state.data.length == 0 && 
                   <div> No options available.</div>
                }
                {this.state.data.length > 0 && 
                  <div className="container top-padding" id="jokes">
                       {this.state.data.map(function(item,i){
                          return(
                                <div key={item['key']} className="card col-md-7">
                                    <div className="card-body">
                                        {item['text']} 
                                    <p><span className="badge badge-secondary">{item.name}</span></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                          )
                       })}
                   </div>
                }
            </div>
         )
    }
}
```

which on start throws this syntax error

```
SyntaxError: http://35.196.142.180/static/js/react-script.js: Unexpected token (52:120)
  50 |                 <div className="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  51 |                   <label className="btn btn-secondary {first_active}">
> 52 |                     <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autoComplete="off" value="Joke" ref_id="{joke_id}" {first_checked} onChange={() => alert('click1')} /> Joke
     |                                                                                                                         ^
  53 |                   </label>
  54 |                   <label className="btn btn-secondary {second_active}">
  55 |                     <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autoComplete="off" value="DadJokes" ref_id="{dadjoke_id}" {second_checked}  onChange={() => alert('click2')} /> DadJokes
```

But where it point to as to where the error is looks fine to me.

This is linked to the render function and the data it's supposed to get from the variables initialized in the constructor.

## Update

I've used the suggestion of adding `this.state.` for checked and it worked like this `checked={this.state.first_checked}`

But this

```
 <label className=`btn btn-secondary ${this.state.first_active}`>
```

Throws this error

```
SyntaxError: http://35.196.142.180/static/js/react-script.js: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text (51:35)
  49 |               <div id="side-nav">
  50 |                 <div className="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
> 51 |                   <label className=`btn btn-secondary ${this.state.first_active}`>
     |                                    ^
  52 |                     <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autoComplete="off" value="Joke" ref_id="{this.state.joke_id}" checked={this.state.first_checked} onChange={() => alert('click1')} /> Joke
  53 |                   </label>
  54 |                   <label className="btn btn-secondary {this.state.second_active}">
```

Comment: I think you're missing a prop name. It should be something like this `prop={first_checked}`

Comment: Specifically, the `checked` property name

Comment: Also, I see this in your code: `className="btn btn-secondary {first_active}"` that isn't the way to interpolate strings, you either need to concatenate the string and the variable, or use string interpolation with backticks and the `${var}` syntax for variables

Comment: Another way to do that is omitting the curly braces entirely if the prop is just a boolean value: `<Component booleanProp otherProp={value} />`

Comment: @Jayce444 so something like this `className="btn btn-secondary ${first_active}"`

Comment: No like this: `className=\`btn btn-secondary ${first_active}\`` use backticks instead of double quotes to wrap it

Comment: @Jayce444 the prop method you suggested throws this `ReferenceError: first_checked is not defined`

Comment: That wasn't me, I just suggested the property name. And it should be `checked={this.state.first_checked}`, since the value is stored in the state

Comment: If you want to omit the prop values, you should destructure them form the component `state` like this: `const { first_checked, second_checke } = this.state;`

Comment: @Jayce444 tried the backticks and got an error. Updating question with it.

Comment: Sorry, the backtick part should wrapped in curly braces, `className={\`something ${blah}\`}`. You can double check "string interpolation in react property" for specific syntax

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
<label className={`btn btn-secondary ${this.state.first_active}`}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
this.state.first_checked
```